# magic trackpad - Ubuntu

Tags: mac, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I've been using a mac in my job for a while now. The only feature I like about it above my ubuntu (on an HP) is the trackpad. I love doing the strokes to move between different files. It really makes things quicker. Is it possible to imitate this feature on my ubuntu laptop? (like maybe there might be something that utilizes my mouse pad on the laptop, as well as the scroller) If that is impossible or doesn't exist then can I set up a magic trackpad to work on Ubuntu on my HP?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/ , it's available in the official repository for the latest release of Ubuntu.

you can also install `utouch`.